# Bitwise mask - how to set different opts?

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

I use a bitmask for access to application and I've got an array:

```
  $arr['view_info'] = 2;
  $arr['view_terminals'] = 4;
  $arr['view_payments'] = 6;
  $arr['view_subdealers'] = 8;
  $arr['view_providers'] = 10;
  $arr['view_users'] = 12;
  $arr['view_reports'] = 14;
```

So, the question is - how can I add permissions, for example - view_terminals and view_reports without permit an access to opts between 4 and 14?

Just the last Q - how to add more than 8 permissions, as I know we have 255 max value in binary sys - so the last one is 128? I've heard about groups.

Comment: You can set up to 32 bits in 32bit integer. Range of unsigned 32bit integer is `0 .. 4,294,967,295`, though, that does not mean that you can set 4,294,967,295 different bits. It just means that you may have 4,294,967,296 "combinations" of bit values. E.g., 65165 would be `0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1110 1000 1101`, with 11 bits being set and 21 bit being unset. If you have 32bit system, then you can use 32bit integers, i.e., store 32 bits in a single integer. To store 128 bits, you should use 4 integers.

Comment: Thanks to everybody, I really appreciate Your attantion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With those values that's pretty hard to do. Your bitmask values should be powers of 2, i.e. 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256 etc. Then you can do `$arr['view_terminals'] | $arr['view_reports']`.

Comment: I accept Your unswer because - I like practice-usefull advises, thanks again.

Comment: Just the last Q - how to add more than 8 permissions, as I know we have 255 max value in binary sys - so the last one is 128?

Comment: No, in a (signed) 32 bit integer you can use 31 unique bits (up to number 2147483647), in a (signed) 64 bit integer 63 (9.223372036854776e+18). Example: http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

Comment: @deceze, why only 31 (and 63)? What's wrong with the last (or first) bit?

Comment: @binary The first bit denotes whether the value is positive or negative in a *signed* integer. In an *unsigned* integer you can use all bits, but not represent negative values. PHP doesn't have unsigned integers.

Comment: @binary But ok, you can use -2147483648/-9223372036854775808 to denote your first bit if you're so inclined. My bad.

Comment: While testing how PHP's bitwise operators work with last bit, I got weird results (that's why I deleted couple of comments). I even thought for some time that PHP indeed has problems with all bits. Though, it turned out that problem is with `base_convert()` which I used for converting bitmasks to binary representations - it converts `1 | (1 << 31)` to `1111111111111111111111111111111` instead of `10000000000000000000000000000001`.. So, use `base_convert()` with caution.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use bitmasks, you need to have the value of your array be power of 2. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)

in your case:

```
$arr['view_info'] = 1;            // 0000000001
$arr['view_terminals'] = 2;       // 0000000010
$arr['view_payments'] = 4;        // 0000000100
$arr['view_subdealers'] = 8;      // 0000001000
$arr['view_providers'] = 16;      // 0000010000 
$arr['view_users'] = 32;          // 0000100000
$arr['view_reports'] = 64;        // 0001000000
```

And set user permission to 2+64 for your user (`0001000010`)

Comment: additions are counter intuitive when working with bitwise operations. You'd better use |, &, ~, etc.

Comment: In other words and in the real app: $userPerms = $arr['view_terminals'] | $arr['view_reports']; // 0001000010 thanks a lot